# Get user password expiration date Powershell and export to CSV

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to get a list of password expiration date on a specific OU with Powershell.

I have an issue to convert "PasswordLastSet" with the exact expiration date.

This is my code :

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Default,OU=BRB02,OU=BE,OU=Consultants,OU=Users,OU=B,OU=ouPROD,DC=F,DC=adfa,DC=local" -Properties PasswordLastSet |
Select-Object -Property "Surname",@{Name="ExpiryDate";Expression={[datetime]::FromFileTime($_."msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed")}} |
Export-Csv D:\password.csv
```

This is what I have in my CSV File :

```
#TYPE Selected.Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser
"Surname","ExpiryDate"
AAA,"01-01-01 01:00:00"
```

Any ideas ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You want to use the attribute "msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed" but you do not tell your `Get-ADUser`to return it for you.  ;-) You should add "msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed" to the parameter -Properties.

Comment: Mmmh... Indeed, thank you !